# Formatting every element in a list based on some function in python

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, chess

I have a class called Move which has a function called getNotation which is used to name a move in chess in a specific manner.

```
class Move(): 
    def __init__(self):
        def getNotation(self):
            return OutputString
```

I have a list class validMoves which contains all the possible moves(each individual element of the list is an instance of the class Move) that can be made for a given GameState.

```
validMoves=[]
```

Now I have a program that returns me a move by looking at the opening book but that program returns the move in the form of OutputString (which is the mentioned in the getNotation function in the Move class). Let us call it the **bestMove**.

My make move function :

```
def makeMove(move):    
    # makes the move on the board
```

Here in my makeMove function , the parameter move can only be an instance of the class Move for the function to work.

So what I did was :

```
for move in validMoves :
    if bestMove == move.getNotation():
        makeMove(move)
```

But I was wondering if there is any other way in which we can make this work because my code has many for loops and I think that it is increasing my runtime.

What I thought of was that if there is any way in which we can modify each element of the list according to a function . Like maybe we can modify each element in validMoves list by appling getNotation without using a for loop , then we can easily check

```
if bestMove in modifiedvalidMoves :
    i = modifiedvalidMoves.index(bestMove)
    makeMove(validMoves[i])
```

The other question if at all this is possible , will this decrease my runtime or not because my perception is that minimizing the number of for loops in code (when it is absolutely not necessary)
increases the speed of the code.

Comment: Have a look into `map()` and `Pool.apply()` https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#map https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply. Also, remember you can `break` out of a loop once you have found the move, you don't need to finish the loop, that will save quite a lot of iterations. I think in this case, `map()` will work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using the `map` class from builtins.

> Make an iterator that computes the function using arguments from each
> of the iterables.  Stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted.

```
result = map(makeMove, validMoves)
```

would return in result an iterator containing each value of validMoves with the function `makeMove` applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)
This let you to access to each elements positionally or namely.